# Pearson's Coefficient for classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, classification, correlation

Can we use Pearson's Correlation Coefficient to calculate the correlation between features and target in the case of a classification problem?

Comment: Yes, you can. Does it make sense to? Not really.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/119835/correlation-between-a-nominal-iv-and-a-continuous-dv-variable

Comment: @DanCarter, I agree it doesn't make sense to use it. So calculating Pearson's r and using it for feature selection is not correct I believe. But I have seen in many places (especially in Kaggle competitions) that people use corr() for  feature selection. Am I missing something here?